# Are there any implementations available online for filter based feature selection methods?

Tags: matlab, classification, weka, feature-selection

The selection methods I am looking for are the ones based on subset evaluation (i.e. do not simply rank individual features). I prefer implementations in Matlab or based on WEKA, but implementations in any other language will still be useful.

I am aware of the existence of CsfSubsetEval and ConsistencySubsetEval in WEKA, but they did not lead to good classification performance, probably because they suffer from the following limitation:

- CsfSubsetEval is biased toward small feature subsets, which may prevent locally predictive features from being included in the selected subset, as noted in [1].
- ConsistencySubsetEval use min-features bias [2] which, similarly to CsfSubsetEval, result in the selection of too few features.

I know it is "too few" because I have built classification models with larger subsets and their classification performance were relatively much better.

[1] M. A. Hall, Correlation-based Feature Subset Selection for Machine Learning, 1999.

[2] Liu, Huan, and Lei Yu, Toward integrating feature selection algorithms for classification and clustering, 2005.

Comment: Did you try genetic algorithm for feature selection?

Comment: No I did not. I tried a feature selection method (i.e. InfoGainAttributeEval in WEKA) that ranks individual features. Then, I build classification models with different number of features. I finally select the model which performs the best on the training dataset to be tested on a test dataset. The number of features selected following this approach was larger than those selected by the aforementioned subset evaluation based methods, and the classification performance was also better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out python [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) simple and efficient tools for data mining and data analysis. There are various implemented methods for [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html), classification, evaluation and a lot of documentations and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

My search has led me to the following implementations:

FEAST toolbox: it is an interesting toolbox, developed by the University of Manchester, and provide implementations of Shannon's Information Theory functions. The implementations can be downloaded from [THIS](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pococka4/MIToolbox.html) webpage, and they can be used to evaluate individual features as well as subset of features.

I have also found [THIS](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26981-feature-selection-based-on-interaction-information) matlab code, which is an implementation for a selection algorithm based on Interaction Information.

Answer (score 0):

**PY_FS: A Python Package for Feature Selection**

I came across this package [[1](https://pypi.org/project/Py-FS/)] which was just released (2021) and contains many methods with reference to their original papers.